# accessing nginx endpoint during a multi-stage docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to crawl a static html site via HTTP as part of building a docker image. When I try to `curl` http://localhost I get connection refused. When I remove the `curl` statement and run the container the static content is available at localhost as expected (including running `curl` inside the container).

Is there any way to access an nginx endpoint during a build?

```
FROM ubuntu AS indexer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
COPY --from=builder /workdir/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN service nginx start
RUN curl http://localhost > /tmp/index.html
```

I've tried waiting for port 80 to be available before I run `curl` but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between each RUN statement, the state of the build 'machine' is destroyed and a new one is started for the next RUN statement. So when you start nginx in one RUN statement, it's gone when you reach the next one.

To do what you're trying to do, nginx needs to be started in the same RUN statement as you do your crawling.

Something like this

```
FROM ubuntu AS indexer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
COPY --from=builder /workdir/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN service nginx start && sleep 10 && curl http://localhost > /tmp/index.html
```

It does seem a little weird that you access the files through nginx rather than the file system. In the (admittedly limited) example you've posted, you could just do

```
RUN cp /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html /tmp/
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'd forgotten the details behind RUN and it makes perfect sense. I've updated my Dockerfile and it works now. The `curl` is just a placeholder and I'll be running a search indexer that requires the target site to be available via HTTP. For others Googling, this is indexing a static Docusaurus site during build so I can run the container with a local search index already built.